# How to setup cron.daily?

Tags: cron, schedule, anacron

I put my shell script inside /etc/cron.daily

I was hoping everything that in that folder would be run daily but my script is not being ran.

Comment: What is the name of your script? Does it conform to the conventions listed in the `DEBIAN SPECIFIC` section of the `cron` manpage?

Comment: solved the problem by adding **#! /bin/bash** to line 1 and renaming **sync.sh to sync**  -- don't know how to answer my own question on here.

Answer (score 10):

Keep in mind that scripts installed in `/etc/cron.{hourly|daily|weekly|monthly}` must be executable, for `run-parts` to process them.

---

Update: Indeed, defining the shebang is also mandatory in cron scripts for `run-parts` to process them. And as a general rule: you should *always* set one.

Comment: Okay, I ran sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/sync.sh  -- we'll see if that works.  All that's in the script is: sh /home/physiii/sync.sh >> /var/log/sync 2>&1 &

Comment: solved the problem by adding **#! /bin/bash** to line 1 and renaming **sync.sh to sync**  -- don't know how to answer my own question on here.